# If I don't want to train in batches and my state is a vector, what should my tensors have for a shape?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use tensorflow to solve a reinforced learning problem. I created an `gym` environment of my own. The state is a one dimensional array (size 224) and there are 170 actions to choose from (0...169). I do not want to train in batches. What I want is to make the most simple version of the RL problem running with tensorflow.

My main problem is, i guess the dimensions. I would assume that TF would allow me to input the state as 1D tensor. But then I get an error when I want to calculate W*input=action. Dimensions error make it hard to know whats right. Also, examples on the web focus on training from images, in batches.

In general, I started in [this](https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-0-q-learning-with-tables-and-neural-networks-d195264329d0) tutorial, but the state is encoded differently, which again makes it hard to follow (especially since I'm not really familiar with python).

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf


env = gym.make('MyOwnEnv-v0')
n_state  = 224
n_action = 170

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Implementing the network itself
inputs1 = tf.placeholder(shape=[1,n_state],dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_state,n_action],0,0.01))
Qout = tf.transpose(tf.matmul(inputs1,W))
predict = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(Qout,1), [n_action,1])

#Below we obtain the loss by taking the sum of squares difference between the target and prediction Q values.
nextQ = tf.placeholder(shape=[n_action,1],dtype=tf.float32)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(nextQ - Qout))
trainer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
updateModel = trainer.minimize(loss)


# Training the network
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

print("input:  ", inputs1.get_shape()
      , "\nW:      ", W.get_shape()
      , "\nQout:   ", Qout.get_shape()
      , "\npredict:", predict.get_shape()
      , "\nnextQ:  ", nextQ.get_shape()
      , "\nloss:   ", loss.get_shape()) 


# Set learning parameters
y = .99
e = 0.1
num_episodes = 2000
#create lists to contain total rewards and steps per episode
jList = []
rList = []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(num_episodes):
        #Reset environment and get first new observation
        s = env.reset()
        rAll = 0
        d = False
        j = 0
        #The Q-Network
        while j < 99:
            j+=1
            #Choose an action by greedily (with e chance of random action) from the Q-network
            a,allQ = sess.run([predict,Qout],feed_dict={inputs1:s})
            if np.random.rand(1) < e:
                a = env.action_space.sample()
            #Get new state and reward from environment
            s1,r,d,_ = env.step(a)
            #Obtain the Q' values by feeding the new state through our network
            Q1 = sess.run(Qout,feed_dict={inputs1:s1})
            #Obtain maxQ' and set our target value for chosen action.
            maxQ1 = np.max(Q1)
            targetQ = allQ
            #targetQ[0,a[0]] = r + y*maxQ1
            targetQ[a,0] = r + y*maxQ1
            #Train our network using target and predicted Q values
            _,W1 = sess.run([updateModel,W],feed_dict={inputs1:s,nextQ:targetQ})
            rAll += r
            s = s1
            if d == True:
                #Reduce chance of random action as we train the model.
                e = 1./((i/50) + 10)
                break
        jList.append(j)
        rList.append(rAll)
print('Percent of succesful episodes: ' + str(sum(rList)/num_episodes) + '%')
```

Comment: Maybe it needs a tf.expand_dims. Paste the error message here.